# Loading of layer fails when using SPYDER

Tags: pyqgis, layers, loading

I configured SPYDER to work with QGIS by setting start file
and setting additionally some system paths

```
@echo off
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18
SET QGISNAME=qgis
SET GRASSNAME=grass\grass-7.2.1
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
SET QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%
SET GRASS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%GRASSNAME%
SET SPYDER="C:\\PROGRA~1\QGIS 2.18\apps\Python27\Scripts\spyder3.exe"

CALL "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%"\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%GRASS%"\etc\env.bat
path %PATH%;%QGIS%\bin
path %PATH%;%GRASS%\lib


set PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages;%PYTHONPATH%
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing;%PYTHONPATH%
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python\plugins;%PYTHONPATH%


start "SPYDER aware of QGIS" /B %SPYDER% %*

import sys
print sys.path

sys.path.append('C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python')

sys.path.append('C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins')

sys.path.append('C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\\processing')
```

after those settings all imports are OK. However when i try to load a layer it fails, but the same code works in QGIS Desktop python environment. My goal is to use SPYDER (or another IDE e.g. Eclipse) to make life easier when debugging/designing QGIS scripts. Is it possible to integrate IDE with QGIS to acheve this ??

here is my code

```
from osgeo import ogr
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.core import QGis, QgsFeature, QgsField, QgsFields, QgsVectorLayer, QgsMapLayerRegistry
from processing.tools.vector import VectorWriter
import csv

from PyQt4.QtGui import *


wb = QgsVectorLayer('C:\\Users\\krzysztof.fajst\\Documents\\PYTHON\\GIS_LV networks\\os with roads feeders and substations.shp', 'os with roads feeders and substations', 'ogr')
layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(wb)
```

also simple

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
```

fails saying qgis name not defined even if I imported iface with

```
from qgis.utils import iface
```

Krzysztof